# como colocar um video dentro de um pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

Como inserir um vídeo em um pdf gerado usando a biblioteca iTextSharp?

Preciso da biblioteca porque ela também faz união de arquivos e assinatura digitais.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando o iTextSharp, faça da seguinte forma:

```
//cria o documento
var doc = new Document();
//caminho do arquivo gerado
String outfile = "c:/documento.pdf";
//pega instância do objeto PdfWriter
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.Create));
//abre o documento para escrita
doc.Open();
//cria uma instância da classe PdfFileSpecification
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, "c:/video.mpg", "video.mpg", null);
//criar e adiciona uma anotação de vídeo no documento
writer.AddAnnotation(PdfAnnotation.CreateScreen(writer, new Rectangle(200f, 700f, 400f, 800f), "Vídeo", fs,"video/mpeg", true));
//fecha o documento
doc.Close();
//visualiza o resultado
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outfile);
```

Os seguintes formatos de arquivo são suportados:

- .aiff  ---    audio/aiff
- .au      ---  audio/basic
- .avi   ---    video/avi
- .mid   ---    audio/midi
- .mov   ---    video/quicktime
- .mp4   ---    video/mp4
- .mp4   ---    audio/mp4
- .mpeg  ---    video/mpeg
- .smil  ---    application/smil
- .swf   ---    application/x-shockwave-flash

**[Fonte](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-pdf-embed-video.htm)**